# How to make pop up screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I wan to make this pop up screen in flutter when I click on add button. So u can help me to make this

[image]

Comment: you can use `showModalBottomSheet` more [information](https://medium.com/codechai/flutter-5-bottom-sheet-2d56bf9f3bc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @eamirho3ein already mentioned, you can use `showModalBottomSheet`. Here is a example code that I've used in my project, in `onPressed` property of `ElevatedButton`:

```
await showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          const Text("Some text"),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/someotherPage");
              },
              child: const Text("Go somewhere")),
        ],
      );
    });
```